# Вращение изображения в PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5

Нужно открыть картинку и вращать ее по часовой стрелке по команде. Вот мой код, в который нужно вставить данную фичу:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QInputDialog,
    QPushButton, QApplication, QTextEdit, QLabel, QLineEdit,QFrame )
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QPalette, QPixmap, QPainter, QPen, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QPointF, QRect
from PIL import Image


class Collector(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.process_timeout)
        self.timer.start(10)  # 50 -- период в милисекундах
        self.phi = 0
        self.lbl = QLabel(self)

    def process_timeout(self):
        if self.phi == 0:
            self.phi += 5
        elif self.phi == 5:
            self.phi -= 5
        self.update()
    def showInputTc_h(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "input Dialog", "Enter data:")
        if ok:
            self.textEdit_Tc_h.setText(str(text))

    def showInputTr(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "input Dialog", "Enter data:")
        if ok:
            self.textEdit_Tr.setText(str(text))

    def showInputTt(self):
        text_Tt, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "input Dialog", "Enter data:")
        if ok:
            self.textEdit_Tt.setText(str(text_Tt))

    def lable_text_button(self):
        Tt = QPushButton("Tt", self)
        Tt.move(480, 130)
        Tc_h = QPushButton("Tc-h", self)
        Tc_h.move(400, 10)
        Tr = QPushButton("Tr", self)
        Tr.move(900, 530)

        self.textEdit_Tt = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textEdit_Tt.setGeometry(QRect(100, 90, 81, 31))
        self.textEdit_Tt.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_Tt.move(400, 130)
        Tt.clicked.connect(self.showInputTt)

        self.textEdit_Tr = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textEdit_Tr.setGeometry(QRect(100, 90, 81, 31))
        self.textEdit_Tr.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_Tr.move(800, 530)
        Tr.clicked.connect(self.showInputTr)

        self.textEdit_Tc_h = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textEdit_Tc_h.setGeometry(QRect(100, 90, 81, 31))
        self.textEdit_Tc_h.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_Tc_h.move(300, 10)
        Tc_h.clicked.connect(self.showInputTc_h)

    def get_image_size(self, img):
        im = Image.open(img)
        (width, height) = im.size
        return (width, height) # вернем ширину и висоту

    def draw_y(self, qp, x0, y0, range_int, const_y):
        for i in range(range_int):
            y0 -= 20 * i
            x1 = x0
            y1 = y0 + 10
            qp.drawLine(QPointF(x0, y0), QPointF(x1, y1))
            y0 = const_y

    def draw_x(self, qp, x0, y0, range_int, const_x):
        for i in range(range_int):
            x0 += 20 * i
            y1 = y0
            x1 = x0 + 10
            qp.drawLine(QPointF(x0, y0), QPointF(x1, y1))
            x0 = const_x

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        pen = QPen(Qt.red, 1)
        qp.translate(0, self.height())
        qp.scale(1, -1)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        pomp = QPixmap()
        QFrame.paintEvent(self, e)

        # width1 = 992,
        # height = 679
        list_y = [(292, 627, 12), (292, 320, 4), (485, 595, 2), (183, 183, 7), (465, 40, 3)]
        list_x = [(150, 637, 7), (310, 385, 6), (486, 607, 27), (183, 64, 14), (480, 64, 6), (690, 64, 16)]
        for y in list_y:
            self.draw_y(qp=qp, x0=y[0], y0=y[1]+self.phi, range_int=y[2], const_y=y[1]+self.phi)

        for x in list_x:
            self.draw_x(qp=qp, x0=x[0]+self.phi, y0=x[1], range_int=x[2], const_x=x[0]+self.phi)

        pen = QPen(Qt.blue, 1)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        list_y_cold = [(5, 627, 15), (240, 386, 3), (183, 317, 4), (296, 183, 2), (485, 312, 3), (652, 562, 15)]
        list_x_cold = [(10, 347, 3), (113, 347, 3), (199, 347, 6), (345, 347, 4), (296, 153, 37), (485, 272, 26), (656, 570, 18)]
        for y_cold in list_y_cold:

            self.draw_y(qp=qp, x0=y_cold[0], y0=y_cold[1]+self.phi, range_int=y_cold[2], const_y=y_cold[1]+self.phi)

        for x_cold in list_x_cold:
            self.draw_x(qp=qp, x0=x_cold[0]+self.phi, y0=x_cold[1], range_int=x_cold[2], const_x=x_cold[0]+self.phi)
        qp.end()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Collector()
    palette = QPalette()
    palette.setBrush(QPalette.Background,       QBrush(QPixmap("images/scheme.jpg")))
    size = w.get_image_size("images/scheme.jpg")
    w.setMaximumSize(size[0], size[1])
    w.setMinimumSize(size[0], size[1])
    w.setWindowTitle('Sun')
    w.setPalette(palette)
    w.lable_text_button()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы вращать картинку, отображаемую с помощью `QPixmap`, можно `QTransform().rotate()` использовать. Код, основанный на [ответе @Jean-Sébastien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31901111/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
"""Usage: rotate-image <image>"""
from PyQt5.Qt import QImage, QLabel, QPixmap, QTransform, QWidget, Qt

class ImageRotor(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, image_path, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.image = QImage(image_path)  # keep original image for rotation
        self.angle = 0

        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)  # NOTE: keep image on screen
        pm = QPixmap(self.image)
        self.resize(pm.width(), pm.height())  # fit window to image
        self.label.setPixmap(pm)
        self.setWindowTitle('PyQt5 Image Rotor')

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        # on any key
        self.angle += 45 if event.key() == Qt.Key_Down else -45
        t = QTransform().rotate(self.angle)
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(self.image).transformed(t))
        return super().keyPressEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:  # wrong arguments
        sys.exit(__doc__)  # print usage
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ImageRotor(sys.argv[1])
    # center on screen
    w.move(app.desktop().screen().rect().center() - w.rect().center())
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

При нажатии на любую клавишу, изображение, указанное в командной строке, вращается на 45 градусов. Если нажать на клавишу <kbd>↓</kbd> («вниз»), то по часовой стрелке вращение.

- начальный размер окна подгонятся под изображение
- используется выравнивание по центру, чтобы при повороте изображение не убегало
- сохраняется оригинальное изображение, чтобы повторные повороты не искажали бы картинку