# Нарисовать повернутый текст на изображении

Tags: python, pyqt5

Мне надо нарисовать текст повернутый на 45 градусов на изображении. Использую QPainter. Нагуглил что есть метод rotate. Делаю `painter.rotate(45)`, но у меня от этого полностью исчезает текст вообще. Pen и Font задал (непрозрачный цвет), вывожу сейчас даже простейшей перегрузкой `painter.drawText(500, 2000, 'Hello world!')` и на изображении пусто... А без вызова rotate все работает нормально. Где подвох?

upd. Я нашел в чем подвох: текст просто уехал за границы изображения. В следствии того что паинтер повернут похоже меняется и система координат... В таком случае вопрос в следующем: как мне пересчитать координаты чтобы они были примерно в том же месте (хоть текст и повернут, ну хотя-бы начинались из того же места)?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Вращение изображения в PyQt5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/528988/23044)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Полагаю, всё получится, если сделать сначала перенос начала координат QPainter, а только потом поверот QPainter. Например, если у нас есть желание нарисовать повёрнутый на угол `angle` (в градусах) текст `myTextString`, начинающийся в точке с координатами `(text_x, text_y)`, можно поступить так (`p` - это QPainter):

```
p.translate(text_x, text_y)
p.rotate(angle)
p.drawText(0, 0, myTextString)
```

В таком случае при повороте вокруг начала координат (которое окажется теперь в точке, куда выполнен перенос) текст далеко не съедет. Если же хочется, чтоб в этой точке была середина строки, то последнюю строчку можно заменить на

```
fm = p.fontMetrics()
width = fm.width(myTextString)
p.drawText(-width / 2, 0, myTextString)
```

Наверное, потом может быть удобно выполнить обратные преобразования координат.